# Converting hex number to cstring

Tags: c++, c

```
void hex2str(int value, char& str);

int a = 0x1014;
int b = 0x7FFF;

char cstr1[8], cstr2[8];
hex2str(a, cstr1);
hex2str(b, cstr2);
```

Now these two char arrays are:

> cstr1[] == {'1', '0', '1', '4', '\0', ...}
>
> cstr2[] == {'7', 'F', 'F', 'F', '\0', ...}

Have no idea, how to achieve that. Any help?

Comment: why can't you use `snprintf()`?

Comment: Pick **a** (one) language.

Comment: The C and C++ are two different languages and in this case yield different answers to your question.  For example, in C++ you can use `ostringstream` and the `hex` manipulator.  The C language does not have this capability.  So choose, C or C++.